# How to handle a very big array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, out-of-memory

I have a program producing a lot of data, which it writes to a csv file line by line (as the data is created). If I were able to open the csv file in excel it would be about 1 billion cells (75,000*14,600). I get the System.OutOfMemoryException thrown every time I try and access it (or even create an array this size). If anyone has any idea how to can take the data into vb.net so I can do some simple operations (all data needs to be available at once) then I'll try every idea you have.

I've looked at increasing the amount of ram used but other articles/posts say this will run short way before the 1 billion mark. There's no issues with time here, assuming it's no more than a few days/weeks I can deal with it (I'll only be running it once or twice a year). If you don't know anyway to do it the only other solutions I can think of would be increasing the number of columns in excel to ~75,000 (if that's possible - can't write the data the other way around), or I suppose if there's another language that could handle this?

At present it fails right at the start:

```
 Dim bigmatrix(75000, 14600) As Double
```

Many thanks,
Fraser :)

Comment: Why do you say that all data must be available at once? The best approach here is to question that statement with all your might. :-)

Comment: Jason, What happens is that I write the data to file line by line. I then need the data transposed (ie columns to rows etc.). I can't see any reasonable way of doing this without all the date. If you can that'd be great! :)

Comment: If you're just trying to transpose a huge CSV, what I'd do is to conceptually break the array into large 1,000 x 1,000 chunks, i.e. read in a thousand rows at a time, compute the transpose of just that, and write each chunk out to a file. Then you can do a merge pass where you read in those chunks (in transposed form) and stream out the final file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this will always require a 64bit operating system and a fairly large amount of RAM, as you're trying to allocate about 8 GB.

This is theoretically possible in Visual Basic targeting .NET 4.5 if you turn on [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That being said, I would recommend using a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of a multidimensional array if possible, as this will remove the requirement of needing a single allocation of 8GB.  (This will also potentially allow it to work in .NET 4 or earlier.)

Comment: Hey Reed,Thanks for the help! I've tried a jagged array on my VS2010 edition and no luck. So I'm downloading and installing .net4.5 :) I'll come back and post if I get it working! Thanks again!

Comment: @user1601928 How much memory do you have?  What OS are you on?

Comment: Currently running it on my laptop: 4gb ram, win 7 - 64, Intel i5 2.3GHz. How would I actually turn on gcAllowVeryLargeObjects? I've downloaded the newest VB, but I don't know exactly how to actually turn it on :/ Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: @user1601928 You'll likely never succeed - you're trying to allocate a single chunk of memory >8gb, but only have 4gb of RAM.  You'd need a system with at least 16gb of ram to have a good chance of success - and maybe more.

Comment: Understandable I suppose. How would I turn on the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects? If I have to get a better system for this I will do! But I looked at trying to turn this on but I have no idea how to start!

Comment: @user1601928 You just put it in your `app.Config` file.  The link shows a full example app.config with it on.

Comment: I've not done anything like this in programming before. I realise I probably seem stupid but how do I access the app.config file? Where is it in the visual studios interface? Thanks for all your help on this! :D

Comment: @user1601928 Right click on the project in solution explorer, choose Add new item..., and add an "Application Configuration File"

Comment: Got it! Just having a go with it now. The whole program takes a day or so to run, I'll post whether it worked when I know :) Seems to be going OK though! Thanks :)

Comment: Right people. For the time being it wont work because of my 4GB system. I've added it all OK just not working because of my system. I'm going to try it again on a 8GB system (I have one available in a few days) and then a 16GB system when I can get my hands on one! Many thanks for everyone's help! :)